# Convert ISO image to VHD

Tags: iso-image, vps, vhd

I want to upload an ISO image to my instance running on Alibaba Cloud but there is no direct way for me to do that as only the VHD format and a few other image formats are supported.

Is there a way to convert an ISO image to VHD so I can then upload the same to Alibaba Cloud instance?

Comment: How about compressing that ISO file (ZIP, 7ZIP)? Or extract whatever in the ISO and put those in a tarball (TAR, TAR.GZ)?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but remember that .iso images are primarily for CD/DVDs, which use a different boot mechanism from regular disks.

If you have a "hybrid CD+USB" .iso image (like many Linux distributions provide), you can convert it without problems – just treat it as a raw dd image. For example:

```
qemu-img convert -f raw -O vpc Foo.iso Foo.vhd
```

```
VBoxManage convertfromraw Foo.iso Foo.vhd --format VHD --variant Fixed
```

But if you have an .iso that was not specifically prepared, and only made for CDs, then you will still be able to upload and attach it but you might won't be able to *boot the VM* from it.

Comment: Cool, I have been able to install qemu and do the conversion. I used the first command. Thanks